# jQuery's plugin Isotope, cutting parts of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Firstable, thanks for being on this page! I am working on an application launcher. I won't talk about it much. The only thing I have to say is that it is bugging. Isotope is really bugged.

You can watch it yourself: http://cloudje.nl/beta/launcher.php

Thank you for taking a look at it ;).

Does anyone have the answer on this question: Why is this bugging?

Please, give an answer if you think you know more about it and know how to fix it. You can view the sourcecode of the page below.

It's a Dutch page and it's full of HTML/CSS errors, I know.

Thanks, Amanush!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"> 
  <title>Cloudje.nl, van harte welkom!</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Cloudje.nl is een manier om als consument of bedrijf veilig in de cloud te werken! Al uw bestanden staan veilig in onze kluis.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/global.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

 html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
   background: url('./images/bg.jpg') no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 #container {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 0 20px; /* top right bottom left */
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 }
 #container h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
text-align:center;
color:lightblue;
 }
 #container #col1 {
 width: 15%;
 float: left;
 }
 #container #col2outer {
 width: 85%;
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
 #col2outer #col2mid {
 width: 60px;
 float: left;
 }
 #col2outer #col2side {
 width: 25%;
 float: right;
 color: lightblue;
 }
 #container #footer {
 float: left;
 width: 870px;
 border-top: #c00 solid 3px;
 }
  #search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:150px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
    background: url(search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="col1">
 <p></p>
 </div>
 <div id="col2outer">
 <div id="col2mid">
 <p><h1>Applicaties</h1></p>
 <div id="apps">
            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'skype'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/skype.png">
                    <p id="text">Skype</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://tumblr.com/','Tumblr')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/tumblr.png">
                    <p id="text">Tumblr</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'firefox'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/firefox.png">
                    <p id="text">Firefox</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href="cloudje:gnome-calculator">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/calculator.png">
                    <p id="text">Rekenmachine</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href="cloudje:teamviewer">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/teamviewer.png">
                    <p id="text">Teamviewer</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/appmarket.png">
                    <p id="text">App Market</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href="cloudje:googleearth">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/googleearth.png">
                    <p id="text">Google Earth</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'gedit'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/notepad.png">
                    <p id="text">Kladblok (gedit)</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'gimp'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/gimp.png">
                    <p id="text">GIMP</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'openshot'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/openshot.png">
                    <p id="text">Openshot</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'filezilla'>         
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/filezilla.png">
                    <p id="text">Filezilla</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://google.com/','Google')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/google.png">
                    <p id="text">Google (zoeken)</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href="cloudje:spotify">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/spotify.png">
                    <p id="text">Spotify</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'libreoffice_--writer'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/word.png">
                    <p id="text">Word (Writer)</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'libreoffice_--calc'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/excel.png">
                    <p id="text">Excel (Calc)</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'libreoffice_--impress'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/powerpoint.png">
                    <p id="text">Powerpoint (Im.)</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'geany'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/geany.png">
                    <p id="text">Geany</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'vlc'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/vlc.png">
                    <p id="text">VLC</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'geogebra'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/geometric.png">
                    <p id="text">Geogebra</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://twitter.com/','Twitter')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/twitter.png">
                    <p id="text">Twitter</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'blender'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/blender.png">
                    <p id="text">Blender</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://chrome.angrybirds.com/','Angry Birds')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/angrybirds.png">
                    <p id="text">Angry Birds</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'calibre'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/calibre.png">
                    <p id="text">Calibre</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'keepassx'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/lock.png">
                    <p id="text">KeePassX</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://linkedin.com/','LinkedIn')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/linkedin.png">
                    <p id="text">LinkedIn</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:xchat>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/xchat.png">
                    <p id="text">Xchat (IRC)</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'liferea'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/liferea.png">
                    <p id="text">Liferea (RSS)</p>
            </div>
            </a>            

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://facebook.com/','Facebook')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/facebook.png">
                    <p id="text">Facebook</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'pidgin'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/pidgin.png">
                    <p id="text">Pidgin Messenger</p>
            </div> 
            </a>

            <a href="cloudje:steam">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/steam.png">
                    <p id="text">Steam</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'inkscape'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/inkscape.png">
                    <p id="text">Inkscape</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'gnome-mplayer'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/mplayer.png">
                    <p id="text">MPlayer</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a onclick="openWindow('http://youtube.com/','YouTube')">
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/youtube.png">
                    <p id="text">YouTube</p>
            </div>
            </a>

            <a href=cloudje:sshpass_-p_"D44N"_ssh_-YC_d.gonning@ssh.cloudje.nl_'nautilus'>
            <div class="app">
                    <img src="./img/apps/filemanager.png">
                    <p id="text">Bestandsbeheer</p>
            </div>
            </a>

        </div>
 </div><br/>
 <div id="col2side">
     <form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
 <p><h4>Alles</h4><h4>Spellen</h4><h4>Grafisch</h4><h4>Internet</h4><h4>Kantoor</h4><h4>Media</h4></p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
        function openWindow(url,name){
            window.open(url,name,'width=1080,height=550,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,location=no'); 
            return false;
        }
    //$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).load(function(){
      var $container = $('#apps');
     $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.app'
      });

    });
    //});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are explicitly asking for a `width: 60px` with the `#col2outer #col2mid` rule. Developer tools help you with these situations. F12 opens them in most browsers. Change it to something larger like `600px` and the icons will be arranged in a grid.

Comment: You are so awasome, I love you so very much! Thank you!